# Move element for mobile only

Tags: search, magento2.4

I use the Porto theme. My search bar is in the porto_header container. When I switch to mobile, I want the search to be in header_top. Is there any way to do this with the XML config, or do I have to duplicate the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using porto theme too,

To edit the header I changed the header.phtml in Smartwave Module. Overwrite that to your custom Module `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/header.phtml`

This is the child for search area:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("top.search"); ?>
```

the line depends on the header_type you are using. Mine is in line **54**

Comment: I've already done that. The issue that I had was moving the search icon to another container for just mobile. I copied the whole div and used css to show/hide them appropriately

Comment: I also did that, the issue here is that if you use the same child to have two top.search in different places, just one will work because of duplicated IDs. With some CSS to display or hide and some properties like "order:1,2-5, etc"  I've achieve the goal